# SQLAlchemy - Calculating total percent of a user input variable

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a database that take in 3 types of data:

```
class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__="data"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    email=db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    height=db.Column(db.Integer)
    color=db.Column(db.String(5))
```

I want to create a function that gets the percentage of users with the same eye color as the user input eye color. I will be emailing this info to the user so I don't think a trigger would be helpful.

This will create a table with the data I need, but it lists every color and I don't know how to grab a specific one from that table:

```
SELECT color, count(*) AS user_count, COUNT(*) * 100.0/ SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() as percent FROM data;
```

This is as close as I can think but it doesn't work. It throws an attribute error

```
def find_pct(color):
    return db.session.query(Data).filter(Data.color==color).count()*100/ sum.count()
```

Comment: well, `sum` is Python built-in and it has nothing to do with SQLAlchemy

Comment: what is sum? Why not  db.session.query(Data).filter(Data.color==color).count()*100/ db.session.query(Data).count() ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @FlorianH Idk I was very confused and trying to work out how to get similar info as the query code and added too much. I figured I would have to add all the columns together to get a total to divide by and didn't think of how you wrote it out. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific colour you can use the aggregate `FILTER` clause in Postgresql:

```
def find_pct(color):
    return db.session.query(
            db.func.count().filter(Data.color == color) * 100.0 /
            db.func.count()).\
        scalar()
```